# How to set the number of digits in Identify Features tool output for a pixel value query in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, identify

I found out that for a raster in float32 Identify Features tool reports rounded values. For example on the screenshot it reports that the pixel value is -0.3, although the real value is -0.300000011920929 (and I can see the real value using "Layer properties/Transparency/Add values from display" ). How to disable rounding in Identify Features tool? I'm using QGIS 2.18.12
[image: Rounded pixel value]
[image: Real pixel value]

Answer (score 1):

the extra digits at the end are a bit confusing; these are due to something called [single-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). As opposed to [Arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). The 'real' value is -0.3

This is a limitation of how floating point numbers are stored in a fixed-sized binary format (float 32 in your case); it's not unique to QGIS.

[This page](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) shows what's happening, if you're curious.

e.g. in python

```
>> import numpy as np
>> print(np.float32(-0.3))
-0.30000001
```

so it looks as if the problem is the other way around, perhaps the display of the transparency dialog could be changed to be more like the identify tool.